# Change Camera in Webview

Tags: javascript, android, webview, camera

I am working on a `WebView` based app in which I am trying to access a link from which I can do a Video Call. All works fine but there is one problem that **I can't switch cameras.**

The link on which Video Call happens by default access rear camera, and I want to change it to front camera. From what I know, to change the cameras around I have to first close the opened camera then switch it back to the one I want.

What happen is that when Video Call url is opened, by default it opens rear camera, if I try to change camera using the site built in setting panel(which shows the both camera on my device), nothing happens.

Now to be sure that I wasn't messing up with my Camera permissions and code, I opened the same link in Chrome, and I observed the same thing. It just didn't change the camera. So I tried again with FireFox, this time, and at the starting of page it prompted which camera to use and it started video call on the front camera as I have selected, however in Firefox also I couldn't switch the camera during the call.

So what I make of this is that, to change the camera using `Camera2` api, I need to close the opened camera first in order to switch camera. **But can someone point out how to get reference of the already opened camera in webview in order to switch it or close it**

What I have tried:

I have manually tried to change camera like this:

```
   @SuppressLint("MissingPermission")
   private void changeCamera() {
    try {
        closeCamera();
        cameraManager.openCamera(String.valueOf(1), mStateCallback, null);
    } catch (CameraAccessException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}



     private void closeCamera() {
                if (null != mCameraDevice) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "closeCamera: Closing Camera");
                    mCameraDevice.close();
                    mCameraDevice = null;
                }


}

private CameraDevice.StateCallback mStateCallback = new CameraDevice.StateCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onOpened(@NonNull CameraDevice cameraDevice) {
            mCameraDevice = cameraDevice;
            Log.d(TAG, "onOpened: **************Camera Opened**************");
        }

        @Override
        public void onDisconnected(@NonNull CameraDevice cameraDevice) {
            cameraDevice.close();
            closeCamera();
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(@NonNull CameraDevice cameraDevice, int error) {
            cameraDevice.close();
        }

    };
```

I have tried calling `changeCamera()` manually(using a button) and as well as after granting camera permission on `webChromeClient` **still camera does not changes**.

I have looked around a lot but could not found anything related to this situation. Please point me in the right direction.